# Ag-Grid: Drag and Drop between Master/Detail grids?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

If I have 2 master rows expanded and their corresponding detail tables visible, can I drag a row from one detail table into the other and receive an event telling me which row it was (so I can update things on the server)?

[This example (for passing data between 2 tables)](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-dragging-to-grid/) makes it look like you have to have an explicit reference to the other table you want to drag to, however, since the master/detail grid generates the children detail grids, I don't have any explicit references that I know of.

[This page about row dragging](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-dragging/) has some good examples as well, but I can't get any events to fire outside of the table where the drag event originated from. I just want to be able to drop a row into any other detail table, and I'll take care of the rest.

For example, if I use [dndSource: true](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-row%20dragging-dndSource) on a row in my columnDefs, I can drag that row to an input field and it will dump the row data as json into the input field. I pretty much just want to be able to dump that same json into another table.

Any ideas?

Note: Master/Detail tables are an enterprise feature.